# Pass ad unit id in xaml to render admob ad

Tags: xamarin.forms, admob

I have added admob ads to my app. Now I want to send the ad unit id from xaml page.

I have implemented it like this.

**Creating a Custom Control**

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MeetupManager.Controls
{
    public class AdControlView : View
    {
    }
}
```

**Adding View Renderer**

```cs
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MeetupManager.Controls.AdControlView), typeof(MeetupManager.Droid.PlatformSpecific.AdViewRenderer))]
namespace MeetupManager.Droid.PlatformSpecific
{
    public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.AdControlView, AdView>
    {
        string adUnitId = string.Empty;
        //Note you may want to adjust this, see further down.
        AdSize adSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
        AdView adView;
        AdView CreateNativeAdControl()
        {
            if (adView != null)
                return adView;

            // This is a string in the Resources/values/strings.xml that I added or you can modify it here. This comes from admob and contains a / in it
            adUnitId = Forms.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.banner_ad_unit_id);
            adView = new AdView(Forms.Context);
            adView.AdSize = adSize;
            adView.AdUnitId = adUnitId;

            var adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            adView.LayoutParameters = adParams;

            adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                            .Builder()
                            .Build());
            return adView;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.AdControlView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control == null)
            {
                CreateNativeAdControl();
                SetNativeControl(adView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updating MainActivity**

```cs
MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "YOUR APP ID HERE FROM AdMob, has a ~ in it");
```

**Updating XAML**

First adding custom xmlns name space:

```xml
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MeetupManager.Controls;assembly=MeetupManager"
```

Then adding the custom control

```xml
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ListView Grid.Row="0"/>
      <controls:AdView Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
```

This is from the tutorial I followed from [Xamarin.Forms: Google AdMob Ads in Android](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/)

It works great. Now what I want is to send ad unit id from xaml. something like this.

```xml
<controls:AdView Grid.Row="1" AdUnitId="testid"/>
```

How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a property in your Custom control, like this:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MeetupManager.Controls
{
    public class AdControlView : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(AdUnitId),
              returnType: typeof(string),
              declaringType: typeof(AdControlView ),
              defaultValue: "");


        public string AdUnitId
        {
            get { return GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty).ToString(); }
            set { SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view renderer

```cs
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MeetupManager.Controls.AdControlView), typeof(MeetupManager.Droid.PlatformSpecific.AdViewRenderer))]
namespace MeetupManager.Droid.PlatformSpecific
{
    public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.AdControlView, AdView>
    {
        //Note you may want to adjust this, see further down.
        AdSize adSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
        AdView adView;
        //*********HERE'S THE CHANGE**********
        AdView CreateNativeAdControl(string adUnitId)
        {
            if (adView != null)
            return adView;            
            adView = new AdView(Forms.Context);
            adView.AdSize = adSize;
            adView.AdUnitId = adUnitId;

            var adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            adView.LayoutParameters = adParams;

            adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                        .Builder()
                        .Build());
            return adView;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.AdControlView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control == null)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(((AdControlView)Element).AdUnitId))
                {
                    string adUnitId = ((AdControlView)Element).AdUnitId;
                    CreateNativeAdControl(adUnitId);
                    SetNativeControl(adView);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is not the safest way than what approach should I take? The ad unit id will change for every page.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my answer is the right way. If this helped you please mark it as an answer

Comment: so will I call it like this 
<controls:AdView Grid.Row="1" AdUnitId="testid"/>
?

Comment: Try it for yourself but my answer is: Yes you can :P

Comment: I was just confused when you said that this was not the right approach and than your implementation seemed to be for that approach. So just to be clear, according to you, the way that I am sending the ad unit id is the best way? and the safest?

Comment: Yes it is the best way, I thought that when you talked about the UnitId you referred to AppId of the application. Please let's try not to make this thread so long. Try the code and add a comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155154/discussion-between-wilson-vargas-and-ahmad-chishti).

Comment: Ok, I get the idea now. I will test this and let you know

Comment: This is working. Thanks.
Just a bonus question. How can we add test devices? I am using

adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                                .Builder()
                                .AddTestDevice("")
                                .Build());

but it does not  seem to work. Shows real ads on my test device. I am using IMEI number for device id

Comment: That's a different question, you can look for more of this in their documentation. If this helped you please mark it as an answer.